# Bosch dishwasher part identification

Tags: dishwasher

Trying to identify a dishwasher part.
Thia dishwasher is bosch, silence plus (I'm in Israel). This part was stuck near the pump inside the dishwasher (specifically the gear of the pump). The dishwasher wouldn't pump water in till I removed it. Can't seem to put it back in and now water won't drain out. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: If this answered your question, type it up as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. There's a round indentation in the shape of this part where the filter goes, it keeps the filter tight and in place.